# Priors in Shannon and Rényi entropies

Tags: bayesian, prior, entropy

[Note: [Cross-posted at Math StackExchange]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863175/priors-in-shannon-and-r%C3%A9nyi-entropies)

I am new to information theory and currently working with Shannon and Rényi entropies. Given the pdf $p_{\theta}(x)$ of a random variable $x$, that is parameterized by variable $\theta$, we write Shannon and Rényi entropies as 
$$H(p) = -\sum\limits_{x} p_{\theta}(x) \log p_{\theta}(x)$$ and 
$$H_{\alpha}(p) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\log\Bigg(\sum\limits_{x} p_{\theta}(x)^\alpha\Bigg),$$ respectively. Through the application of L'Hopital rule, it can be shown that as $\alpha\rightarrow1$, $H_{\alpha}(p)$ approaches $H(p)$.

In case the pdf $\lambda(\theta)$ of $\theta$ is also known, the Shannon entropy is obtained by replacing $p_{\theta}(x)$ by $\lambda({\theta})p_{\theta}(x)$ in its expression, i.e., 
$$H(p;\lambda) = -\sum\limits_{x} \lambda({\theta})p_{\theta}(x) \log (\lambda({\theta})p_{\theta}(x)).$$

I am not sure how to obtain Rényi entropy in this case. If I replace $p_{\theta}(x)$ by $\lambda({\theta})p_{\theta}(x)$ in the expression of the Rényi entropy, then I get 
$$H_{\alpha}(p;\lambda) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\log\Bigg(\sum\limits_{x} (\lambda(\theta)p_{\theta}(x))^\alpha\Bigg).$$
However, after application of L'Hopital's rule, this expression does not reduce to $H(p;\lambda)$ as $\alpha\rightarrow1$.

Could someone point out what I might be missing here? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

-RD